# Отклонить-и-править автора ответа утверждает правку

Tags: дефект, модерация, очередь-проверок

На примере [вот этой проверки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/292426) выяснил странный баг: если в эту проверку приходит автор поста, то нажатие им кнопки отклонить-и-править (возможно и просто "отклонить"?) почему-то приводить к утверждению правки.

> @AK А это бага аппрувера. Я выбрал "отклонить и править", чтобы внести
>   коррективы в запрос про сообщению автора. В этот момент правка была
>   отклонена другими модераторами, у меня высветилось сообщение о том,
>   что правка отклонена, с единственной кнопкой "принять". После нажатия
>   на неё я попал на страницу с НЕотклоненной корректировкой. Так что все
>   претензии к косяку в движке. **@Akina**

Налицо дефект.

Во-первых, приходится править потом пост ещё раз; во-вторых, двум другим проверяющим ставится неверная статистика в очереди.

Comment: На MSE планируете задать? Проблема, в общем-то, в движке.

Comment: Что-то похожее вроде https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242377/260198